# query scheduling and setup mail alert in google cloud

Tags: google-bigquery, alert

I want to schedule one Google Cloud query for every day, and I also want to receive email alerts whenever any table's size exceeds 1 TB. Is it possible that?

Answer (score 0):

With `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` the size of all tables in a project and a region can be obtained. The `error` raises an alert and for schedulded queries an email notification can be set.

For each region the project is using you need to set up a schedule query.

```
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(summary),if(count(1)>0,error(concat(count(1)," tables too large, total: ",sum(total_logical_bytes),"  list: " ,STRING_AGG(summary) )),"")
FROM
(
  SELECT
    project_id,
    table_name,
    SUM(total_logical_bytes) AS total_logical_bytes,
    CONCAT(project_id,'.',project_id,'=',SUM(total_logical_bytes) ) AS summary
  FROM
    `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE
  GROUP BY
    1,
    2
  HAVING
    total_logical_bytes> 1024*1024 # 1MB Limit
  ORDER BY
    total_logical_bytes DESC
    
  )
```

The inner query obtaines all tables in `eu`-region and filters these above 1 MB. The outer query checks for more than one item in the `if` statement and raises an alert with `error`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks samuel, do have any idea how setup mail alert on that?

Comment: @ShubhamSantoshwar Please set up a schedule query.

Comment: i want know if any table exceed 1tb limit then automatically i want mail  and that mail which are table name and storage also should be mentioned.

Comment: As shown in my answer, you need to set up a scheduled query and check the "send email notification". Of course you need to set up the run of the schedule query, daily should be enough for most cases. If you run it every hour (`every 01:00`) than you have a half TB of query cost billed each month. The email is only send to you. But we use email rules by our email program to forward these to further people.